# Custom Model - "no such file to load -- odbc"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, odbc

I'm trying to create a custom model to interface with a database that isn't supported navtively by Rails or through the OpenLink ODBC driver.  For some reason, I'm getting the following error:

no such file to load -- odbc

I'm at a lost as to why this is occurring as the ruby-odbc gem is in the GEM_PATH and I have a small script that tests this to ensure that the connection works and it worked perfectly.  Does Rails ignore the gem_path?  Is there something else I need to configure?  I checked the GEM_PATH in Rails by writing it out to the browser and it matches what I saw in a terminal window.

FYI: I'm using rvm to manage ruby and all of my gems.  Not sure if this makes any difference, though it really shouldn't from what I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your Gemfile include something like the following

```
gem 'ruby-odbc'
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!  That was almost it.  I actually had to set it to ruby-odbc and now it looks like the DB connection is working.