# Ruby on Rail gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems

I'm trying to run rake commands on my local SQL server database using ODBC. I have setup the ODBC connections and thought I had the rails end covered however, i'm running into this error.

Please install the sqlserver adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter)

I have the following gems installed:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.5)
actionpack (3.0.5)
activemodel (3.0.5)
activerecord (3.0.5, 1.15.6)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.0.10)
activeresource (3.0.5)
activesupport (3.0.5, 1.4.4)
arel (2.0.9)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)
dbd-odbc (0.2.4)
dbi (0.4.1)
deprecated (3.0.0, 2.0.1)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.15)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (2.0.2, 1.6.0)
odbc-rails (1.5)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.2)
rack-mount (0.7.1, 0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.5)
railties (3.0.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (3.5.3, 2.5.8)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.25)
```

Am I missing a gem? What else do I need to get this running on my windows box?

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add such line in your %APP_ROOT%/Gemfile

```
 gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

Comment: Hi, that helped. Thank you. I'm now getting another error "no such file to load -- odbc" Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to add `gem 'odbc'`. Following this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787013/custom-model-no-such-file-to-load-odbc)

Comment: Yeah i tried that, I get the error "Could not find gem 'odbc (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile."

Comment: You can try [this guide](http://rhnh.net/2010/10/10/rails-3-ruby-1-9-2-windows-2008-and-sql-server-2008-tutorial). But I cann't provide some advanced help to you already -- my main platform is *nix :( [Ruby-ODBC official site is here](http://www.ch-werner.de/rubyodbc/)

Comment: I highly advise using TinyTDS, see the wiki page on it here. We update it regularly. https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds

Answer (score 1):

Also, your way behind on the times. First the DBI/DBD-ODBC were removed from the adapter stack about a year ago. Also, the easiest way (and best performance) is to use TinyTDS for the connection mode. See there wiki here.

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds